# Regd. WSO2 ESB Kafka Consumer Project

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2-esb

I am creating two WSO2 ESB Integration projects for the purpose of one for Kafka Message Producer and second for Kafka Message Consumer. I created Kafka Message Producer successfully on invocation of REST API and message going to be dropped on the topic. When I am creating Kafka message consumer there is no transport such as Kafka for proxy to listen on and as per the documentation we need to use IP endpoint for the same. My requirement is Kafka Message should be received at consumer automatically from a topic (similar to JMS Consumer) when message is available on the topic. So how can i achieve that using IP endpoint with Kafka details.

any inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue with separate wso2 consumer Integration project. Its getting issues while creating the inbound endpoint type as kafka.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consume messages in a Kafka topic using an EI server, you need to use Kafka inbound endpoint. This inbound endpoint will periodically poll the messages from the topic and the polling interval is configurable. Refer to the documentation [1] for more information on this.

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Kafka+Inbound+Protocol

Comment: Hi Shanaka Premarathna, i am ok to create inbound endpoint in EI but my requirement here is to create ESB integration project on integration studio to receive the message from Kafka server. I have created similar WSO2 ESB project for Kafka Message Producer.

Comment: you can use the integration studio to create the inbound endpoint. Similar to creating a proxy service.

Comment: Hi Shanaka Premarathna, I created the inbound endpoint in the integration studio but thats not getting receive the message from kafka topic. If you dont mind can you please create kafka consumer integration project to receive the message from kafak topic.

Comment: Moreover, when we try to create a separate publisher and subscriber projects then the connector projects getting conflict in micro integrator while starting the other getting uninstalled and connection is getting lost.